# trying to understand JVM's JIT behavior

Tags: java, jvm, jit

I am playing with the -XX:+PrintCompilation flag.  Running a relatively complex operation in a tight loop for about 3 days now, I have completed 26K iterations which are all identical, and yet I am still seeing JIT happening:

```
135245570 11820       3       org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl::setDTDHandler (6 bytes)   made zombie
135245571 12195       3       oracle.net.ano.AnoComm::i (11 bytes)
135245592 9715   !   4       org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils::closeStatement (41 bytes)   made zombie
135245592 10054   !   3       com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment::get (210 bytes)   made zombie
135245605 12196       3       oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineStream::marshalB1Array (14 bytes)
136786126 12197   !   4       net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.jdbcapi.ConnectionSpy::prepareStatement (69 bytes)
136786158 9045   !   3       net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.jdbcapi.ConnectionSpy::prepareStatement (69 bytes)   made not entrant
137012330 12198   !   3       java.net.InetAddress::getAddressesFromNameService (245 bytes)
137012337 12201       3       java.net.URI$Parser::parse (265 bytes)
137012343 12203       3       java.net.URI::access$1002 (7 bytes)
137012344 11499       3       sun.nio.cs.US_ASCII$Decoder::decode (62 bytes)   made zombie
137012347 12202   !   3       java.net.URI$Parser::parseAuthority (256 bytes)
137012350 12199   !   3       java.net.InetAddress::checkLookupTable (99 bytes)
137012352 12200   !   3       java.net.InetAddress::cacheAddresses (52 bytes)
137045611 12204       4       java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter::call (14 bytes)
137045710 9432       3       java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter::call (14 bytes)   made not entrant
137048986 12205       3       oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine::marshalKEYVAL (129 bytes)
137077651 12206   !   3       oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatementWrapper::registerOutParameter (297 bytes)
137077666 12207   !   3       oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement::registerOutParameter (329 bytes)
138816046 12208       4       oracle.net.ano.AnoComm::a (34 bytes)
138816051 11867       3       oracle.net.ano.AnoComm::a (34 bytes)   made not entrant
138816051 10955       3       java.util.Hashtable$Enumerator::next (27 bytes)   made zombie
138884752 12209       3       java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl::finalize (5 bytes)
```

What would be the explanation for why this is happening?

Comment: “relatively complex operation” and “a tight loop” is a contradiction. If the operation is inside the loop, you have either, a complex operation or a tight loop. In the former case, it’s imaginable that it still takes different code paths occasionally.

Comment: By tight loop i meant that it just does the same exact thing over and over.  The operation is relatively complex (multiple tables read and written to) but it should always take the same code path.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the codepath is always the same and it's unlikely that Hotspot will find new hotspots (that will maybe trigger a mass-invalidation of jitted blocks), it can still invalidate some of the blocks it has jitted for other reasons.

This is dependent on how this JIT engine has been implemented, look at those `made zombie` and `made not entrant`, you are clearly hitting some specific conditions that invalidate the code block the JIT has produced and triggering a new compilation.

Comment: but what could invalidate hashtable enumerator next method?  I ran this for like 2 weeks and recompilations slowed down significantly but where still happening all the time.